# Flutter firebase Authentication disabled account

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

Flutter Firebase Authentication
Can I create by default disabled firebase account with createUserWithEmailAndPassword??

Answer (score 0):

Allowing the user to sign upinto a default disabled state isn't possible with only the client SDK.  You would need to take some manual action to disable the user, or write some backend code using the Firebase Admin SDK to [update that user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user) are your two options.

You could write an [authentication trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events) using Cloud Functions that disabled the account right after it's created, but the user account would still be enabled for a short period of time until that function triggers.